# How to set a form status to invalid, so it won´t be submitted using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to set a form status to invalid because I need to change some fields' attributes before I submit the form.

Comment: I made a click event of the button, did all the stuff I needed and after that, I submit the form. 
$(btnName).click(function(){
//all my stuff
$(frmName).submit();
});

I had to change my input element to type button instead of submit

Answer (score 3):

Capture the event, and prevent it from firing unless all of your elements have valid values.

```
$("#myForm").submit(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     // do all your validation stuff here.

     // when it is valid
     // then do this:
     // $("#myForm").submit();

});
```

Comment: WHAT!??!?! and cause an endless loop?

Comment: what do you mean an infinite loop? He can submit it once the values are correct.

Comment: but that is your submit handler.. and you are going to keep triggering it?

Comment: It is going to return false until all the values are valid

Comment: ok.. think about this.. inside the submit.. it passes.. then you trigger the submit handler again `$("#myForm").submit();` ... then it passes validation again.. then you trigger again

Comment: It might work if you trigger the native submit.. so it doesn't loop through the jQuery submit handler again `$("#myForm")[0].submit()`

Comment: oh ok. So instead of submit I can replace that with `return`

Answer (score 1):

Without jquery if desired:

```
<form onSubmit="myFunction()">
...
</form>
```

Then the JavaScript myFunction() will run first and you can do your validation there.  The form will submit after myFunction() is complete, UNLESS you have the function `return false;`
So you can do:

```
function myFunction() {
  //cleanup first (trim etc.)
  //check validation next
  if([does not validate])
  {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Actually, thats why I needed to prevent submit, because I needed all my changes made when MyFunction() got executed.